# Is there a way to use cpp.doxygen syntax file and my own cpp.vim syntax file?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

At the bottom of my file, I'd to have something like this:

```
// vim: syntax=cpp.doxygen
```

Only, when I do that, it breaks my auto-load of my own cpp.vim.

```
au BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.cpp          so $HOME/vim/presentrack.vim
```

I write code where my with C++ classes have variable members that start with `f_` and with my syntax I see those in a specific color.

Also I define some global variables (rarely, though) which start with `g_`. Again I give them a special color.

I also like the special doxygen highlighting because it shows me whether I mistype something without having to run doxygen (it helps fixing some mistakes quickly.)

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds?

Right now, my `presentrack.vim` has an include:

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/cpp.vim
```

and I would imagine I would have to instead include doxygen and not have doxygen at the bottom of my .cpp file?

What I'd like is a way that both syntaxes would co-exist, although I would imagine that is not supported, I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 2):

> when I do that, it breaks my auto-load of my own cpp.vim.
>
> ```
> au BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.cpp          so $HOME/vim/presentrack.vim
> ```

The canonical way to extend the syntax highlighting for the `cpp` filetype would be to put your custom rules in `~/.vim/after/syntax/cpp.vim`.  That will automatically be loaded for you.

Comment: Or if OP really likes the name presentrack (could be inhouse company style related), could use `~/.vim/after/syntax/cpp/presentrack.vim` (i think)

Comment: I was going to suggest something like that, but the `{filetype}_foo.vim` and `{filetype}/foo.vim` naming only works for `ftplugin/`.

Comment: Darn. Thats actually kind of disappointing.